# Firefox and Chrome CSS Absolute Positioning problem

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, google-chrome, positioning

This is the website in question: http://www.eportfolio.jameswmann.com/
In the 'Music' section. The image 'new'.

.new displays correctly in Google Chrome - In Firefox, it's completely in the wrong spot.

This problem could be fixed if jQuery would animate my span using 'block' or 'inline-block' rather than just 'inline'

I'm not sure if I should fix the jQuery animation or fix the placement issues between the 2 browsers.

Comment: I cant help you with your question, but great looking site bud!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a css reset stylesheet to set everything to the same, and define the tags you want to so everything is consitent across all browsers. try this one:

http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/

Comment: oh, maybe i read that wrong, but you could still try it, but ill take a look at the site really quick

Comment: I already had a CSS reset but I tried the one you linked, it actually messed up some of my <li>'s haha

Comment: ah, sorry about that, and i see where the new tag is misaligned, it looks to be way off, that is kind of strange, ill try to look into it more when i get a second

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) or even its [Stripped Down version](http://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate/zipball/v1.0stripped) to achieve a proper, industry-recognized reset that will help mitigate these issues.

Comment: Okay. I used the HTML5 Boilerplate CSS Reset. It didn't change much.